# Laravel 5.3 finding correct option of 4 options of an Mcq

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have an ''MCQ'' saved in my database which has 4 ''options''. Each option has a ''answer'' boolean column to show whether an option is true or false. Now I have the ''MCQ'' object with its ''options''. So, without making any query how can i find the correct option object in my controller

Comment: Please provide a graphic of your database/table structure

Comment: Are are your models set up?

Comment: Yes every thing  is setup .  I  can get  the  options  by  "$mcq->options" suppose inside  my  options  field  there is a  boolean  column "answer".  How can I get the option  with  "answer=1"" for  a  particular mcq . If an  mcq  option  is  false  than  answer is 0

Comment: You question is not clear enough. What are options, possible answers? Please provide a graphic of your tables, or explain your table structure.

Comment: Schema::create('options', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('number')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('mcq_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('body');
            $table->boolean('answer');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: Schema::create('mcqs', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('body');
                $table->timestamps();
            });

Comment: mcqs and options(possible answers) table scheme